# Azure Containers - with 10 different services

Tags: azure, docker-compose, containers

I have an application which has 10 different services including nginx, celery and postgresql.  Is it possible to deploy this using Azure Container Instances?

I tried few times including taking image from the ACR but I am not able to get this work.  I only see one container instead of all 10.  I thought docker compose will automatically create all the instances but I am struggling understand the exactly issue.

Here is the sample docker-compose file. Any guidance would be really helpful.

```
services:
  app: &app
    image: registry....../app
    build:
      context: .
    env_file: variables.env
    volumes:
      # - ./app/:/usr/src/app/
      - static:/usr/src/app/static
      - media:/usr/src/app/media
    command: /bin/true

  web:
    <<: *app
    command: uwsgi --ini /usr/src/app/uwsgi.ini
    expose:
      - 8000


  channelserver:
    <<: *app
    command: daphne --bind 0.0.0.0 --port 5000 -v 1 APP.asgi:application
    expose:
      - 5000

  db:
    image: postgres:10.5-alpine
    volumes:
      - postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
    env_file: variables.env

  redis:
    image: redis:3.0-alpine

  nginx:
    image: registry...../nginx
    build: ./nginx
    environment:
      - SERVERNAME=${DOMAIN:-localhost}
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: $PWD/nginx/nginx.conf
        target: /etc/nginx/conf.d/nginx.conf
      - static:/usr/src/app/static
      - media:/usr/src/app/media
    ports:
      - 8080:80

   celery-main:
    <<: *app
    command: "celery worker -l INFO -E -A [APP] -Ofair --prefetch-multiplier 1 -Q default -c ${CELERY_MAIN_CONC:-10} --max-tasks-per-child=10"

  celery-low-priority:
    <<: *app
    command: "celery worker -l INFO -E -A [APP] -Ofair --prefetch-multiplier 1 -Q low-priority -c ${CELERY_LOW_CONC:-10} --max-tasks-per-child=10"

  celery-gpu: &celery-gpu
    <<: *app
    environment:
      - KRAKEN_TRAINING_DEVICE=cpu
    command: "celery worker -l INFO -E -A [APP] -Ofair --prefetch-multiplier 1 -Q gpu -c 1 --max-tasks-per-child=1"
    shm_size: '3gb'

  flower:
    image: mher/flower
    command: ["flower", "--broker=redis://redis:6379/0", "--port=5555"]
    ports:
      - 5555:5555

  mail:
    build: ./exim
    image: registry....../mail
    expose:
      - 25
    environment:
      - PRIMARY_HOST=${DOMAIN:-localhost}
      - ALLOWED_HOSTS=web ; celery-main ; celery-low-priority; docker0

volumes:
   static:
   media:
   postgres:
   esdata:
```

Answer (score 0):

To deploy multiple containers in the Azure Container Instance, you can use the [YAML](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-multi-container-yaml) file and the Azure [Template](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-multi-container-group), these two ways can deploy the containers directly to ACI. In addition, you can also use the docker-compose file following this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/tutorial-docker-compose).

And if you have more questions about this issue, you can provide details and I'm willing to help you.

Comment: Thanks, I actually tried one of the tutorial above but It wasn't working.  I will give it a try one more time and confirm here again.

Comment: @SharePointer Give the things you have tried. I will take a look to find what is the issue for you.

Comment: @SharePointer Any updates on this question? Does it solve your problem?